# Play one audio at a time with avplayer in UITableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, avplayer

I am using UITableview to play audio using **AVPlayer** and I want to **play one audio at a time in cell**. I have created a separate instance for each AVPlayer object. what I need actually is I need to play one audio at a time.
so if I play audio in one cell and tap on other cell audio button then both are playing at same time.

Anyone has any idea how can we stop playing audio of another cell.

Comment: yes, u can do it only use one instance and when tap on cell first stop the player and load new URL and play the audio on did select methods it using conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayerStk; // Define variable in app delegate

    #define app_delegate ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])   // define in common class

 Add this line where you want to play
     if (!!app_delegate.audioPlayerStk) {
        !app_delegate.audioPlayerStk = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init];
    }

   // self.audioPlayerStk.delegate = self;
    [!app_delegate.audioPlayerStk playURL:[NSURL URLWithString:LIVE_STREAM_URL]];
```